# Cross browser compatability issue

Tags: javascript, css

I am developing a website and it is working fine on all the browsers but Google Chrome.
I need to set margin of an object just for Chrome. navigator.appName returns "**Netscape**" for both mozilla and chrome. navigator.appCodeName gives **Mozilla** for both browsers and userAgent returns this

"**Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4**"

What should i do?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns true when using Chrome:

`(/Chrome/).test(navigator.userAgent)`

Answer (score 1):

Try [something](http://davidwalsh.name/detecting-google-chrome-javascript) based on the **userAgent** property, the most reliable one:

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

JUST if you are using jQuery you can use:

```
$.browser.webkit
```

Comment: This returns also true when using Safari and needs a library like jQuery

Comment: yes cause if you set margins on chrome you are setting them for all webkit browsers i hope!! (like Safari too)